# Inputs won't print to output .txt file. No errors, no warnings

Tags: python

I'm trying to get these inputs to print to an .txt file. I've had it working fine at some points but as  II altered the code it stopped working. It has no errors or warnings. It just won't print to output file = "workhours2.txt'

```py
file = open('Workhours2.txt' , 'a')

if DT1 == "y".lower():
    print("Date: ",DT2, file=file)
elif DT1 == "n".lower():
    print("Date: ",DT3, file=file)
if  DS == "y".lower():
    print("Position: Diver", file=file)
elif DS == "n".lower():
    print("Position: Supervisor", file=file)
    print("Start Time: ",shrs, file=file)
    print("Finish Time: ",fhrs, file=file)
    print("Travel Time: ",thrs,"hrs", file=file)
    print("Job or Client: ",job, file=file)
    print("Depth Allowance in meters: ",dp, file=file)
    print("Welding allowance in mm: ", wd1, file=file)
    print("Notes: ",nts, file=file)
    print(file=file)
```

Comment: What are `DT1`, `DS` etc

Comment: Have you tried replacing all the `print` functions with `file.write` functions? If that doesn't work either, perhaps none of your conditions are being met? You could test for that by adding an `else` at the end, which would always run if none of the other conditions are met.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] first. Also, take the [tour] an read [ask].

Comment: DT1 is todays date input from datetime module and DS is the job position input

Answer (score 0):

Python's `print` will print to your console, not the file. You are looking for `file.write`

Answer (score 0):

Some problems with your code:

1. The print command prints to the console (stdout). To print to the file, you need to do file.write
2. You should close the file before ending the program. It is good practice to do so.

```py
file = open('Workhours2.txt' , 'a')

if DT1 == "y".lower():
    file.write("Date: " + str(DT2))
elif DT1 == "n".lower():
    file.write("Date: " + str(DT3))
if  DS == "y".lower():
    file.write("Position: Diver")
elif DS == "n".lower():
    file.write("Position: Supervisor")
    file.write("Start Time: " + str(shrs))
    file.write("Finish Time: "str(fhrs))
    file.write("Travel Time: "+str(thrs)+"hrs")
    file.write("Job or Client: "+str(job))
    file.write("Depth Allowance in meters: "+str(dp))
    file.write("Welding allowance in mm: "+str(wd1))
    file.write("Notes: "+str(nts))
    file.write()
file.close()
```

Comment: File write its is. The problem now it writes to file in a linear fashon in the output .txt file instead of writing to file in a column like its presented in the code